# Disbale HTTPS in asset

Tags: laravel

I have migrated my laravell 7 sites to a new host site is displaying all data but CSS, JS and Route not working in chrome console it is showing err with `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` all URL of assets and routes are using https, how to disable https and use http?

Comment: I have used this in .env file but still same issue `REDIRECT_HTTPS=false`

Comment: your question is not that clear to me, you are saying your routes are not working as they are https, so you want then http ?

Comment: yes I want http urls not with https, also css and js file using https. I want to remove https and server http in url, here is the url of site http://54.157.54.75/

Answer (score 0):

You can use as middleware.

```
URL::forceScheme('http');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by commenting below code in htaccess

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```